# Exact sequence from $G=G_0\supset G_1\supset G_2\supset\cdots\supset G_r=\{e\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

This is Exercise 5.3 from [Algebra: Chapter 0](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf).

> Given a normal series of subgroups \begin{equation}G=G_0\supset G_1\supset G_2\supset\cdots\supset G_r=\{e\},
> \end{equation} construct an exact sequence of groups using $\{e\}, G$ and $H_j=G_j/G_{j+1}$ to connect $\{e\}$ and $G$.

I am not sure what the author is asking for. Starting from $\{e\}$, I think the only natural sequence involving only $\{e\}, H_j$ and $G$ is of the form \begin{equation}
\{e\}\longrightarrow G_{r-1}/G_{r}\longrightarrow G_{r-2}/G_{r-1}\longrightarrow\cdots.
\end{equation}  However this is not exact.

Can someone give a hint?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misread the exercise. It says

> Show how to 'connect' $\{e\}$ to $G$ by means of $r$ exact sequences of groups, involving only $\{e\}$, $G$ and the quotients $H_i = G_i/G_{i+1}$.

So you are not supposed to find a single exact sequence connecting $\{e\}$ to $G$, but rather $r$ seperate ones. I think the exercise in that form still contains a typo and should read "involving only $\{e\}$, $G_i$ and the quotients $H_i = G_i/G_{i+1}$". Then you can take (writing $1$ for $\{e\}$)
\begin{matrix}
1 & \to & G_1 & \to & G & \to & H_0 & \to & 1,\\
1 & \to & G_2 & \to & G_1 & \to & H_1 & \to & 1,\\
 & & & & \vdots & & & & \\
1 & \to & G_{r-1} & \to & G_{r-2} & \to & H_{r-2} & \to & 1,\\
1 & \to & 1 & \to & G_{r-1} & \to & H_{r-1}  & \to & 1.
\end{matrix}

Comment: Thanks! But then what is the point of this exercise?